# Is anyone using DynamicLinkDAO or DynamicLinkInfoHomeBaseLegacy?

Tags: discussion

Is there anyone using either `DynamicLinkDAO` or `DynamicLinkInfoHomeBaseLegacy` in SDL Tridion Content Delivery?

This data is only stored in database (`DYNAMIC_LINKS` table) but never used or retrieved from the Broker database (either with Broker API or any other way).

Is there anyone using this?

Comment: I've just added a close vote on the grounds that this is off-topic. It /would/ belong on trex

Comment: @DominicCronin Agreed - it should probably be migrated back rather than closed, though.

Comment: I can't find the option to migrate it back :/

Comment: I reopened it in the hope that I would be able to migrate it then, but I can't find the option either.

Comment: Tried to migrate this and like Rob and Bart failed. Last time this came up I was able to migrate using the following sequence but it looks like they removed the option to type in a sitename when you close a meta question as belonging elsewhere:
'close -> off topic -> belongs on another site in the stack exchange network ->type site name in box and hit vote to close '

Comment: Given this I am just going to close.

Comment: This question really belongs on the main site but the option to migrate it there doesn't seem to exist anymore.